# Executing Linux command as root in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, command

I want to execute a linux command as a root user, from my C++/Qt code.
Ultimately a a dialog requesting root pass should be implemented, but for no I can hard-code root password.

This is what I done so far:

```
QProcess p;
p.start( "dmidecode" );
p.waitForFinished(-1);

QString p_stdout = p.readAllStandardOutput();
QString p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();
```

And it is working for commands that do not request root privileges. But I want to implement commands like "zypper up" or "dmidecode" which I can't execute without a root password.

Probably something can be done with `void QProcess::setEnvironment ( const QStringList & environment )`?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it can't be done in Qt alone (in a standard or at least standardish way). There is a standard way in KDE though. Try searching their documentation.

Comment: You need to use desktop managers' interface to run command as root. For ubuntu you can use gksudo for password interface for example.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot elevate your privileges if you run as a normal user unless you're suid, which you probably don't want for the whole application.
The way it's done is through an external helper; you want something that does sudo not su as in Ubuntu the root account is locked; gksudo or kdesudo depending on the running environment. One of those should be preinstalled on any modern linux distro, or you could deploy a copy with your application.
Of course it will not work if the current user does not have the rights to run stuff through sudo, but this is a normal security measure and you shouldn't work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule to the list of sudoers for a special user, and execute the command as this user as:

```
sudo *some command*
```

You can use [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) or [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html) for this.

To see how to add a rule to the list of sudoers, see [sudoers manual](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html)

Comment: Is there an more elegant solution without having to create another user?

Comment: @sivic Do not create another user, but add the current user to the list of sudoers and allow them to execute some command which only root can execute

Answer (score 0):

How about keep using your code anyway but make a shell script for your app and put it on /usr/bin? I did it and works well everytime.

```
#it is the shell script code
#!/bin/bash
gksudo /usr/lib/your_qt_app
```

Than simply you just need to call the shell script file. Name it **myscript** and open your bash. Type there:

```
myscript
```

Notice the *gksudo* command above. That command elevates you to be root. I don't know simpler answer than this. Maybe it doesn't help, but I use this way.