# How to get root permission inside Qt program?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shell, root

I need to create directory inside root directory using a qt widget application.

```
void Home::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    system("mkdir /bin/mydir");
}
```

But,how to get root privilege before making folder inside /bin folder

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036588/cqt-executing-linux-command-as-root

Answer (score 3):

you can get root password using pkexec command inside programming like below:

```
 void Home::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
    system("pkexec mkdir /bin/myDir");
 }
```

or you can try to using `QProcess` class, however for your purpose the pkexec is enough.But in this mode you have to enter password manually, but if you want to get root permission without entering password manually and you could enter your password inside of the code then you may consider the below code:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("echo your_password | sudo -S mkdir /bin/myDir");
```

Answer (score 0):

A program cannot gain root privileges after it has been started; it is only permitted to (either temporarily or finally) drop privileges.

The best approach is usually to invoke a program such as *gksudo* or *ksudo*, which the system will invoke as root, at which point they temporarily drop root privileges, query the user for consent, close their connection to the GUI system, regain root privileges and execute the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to access some resources which requires root privilege, you have to run that application as root.
e.g

```
sudo your_application_name
```

or login as root and then run that application.