# QProcess::execute with su command

Tags: linux, qt, tar, su

I am trying to call `tar` from a `Qt` project:

```
QProcess::execute("/bin/su", {"-", "user", "-c", "\'/bin/tar xpf /tmp/smt.tbz2 -C /tmp\'"})
```

Bit I am getting:

```
-su: /bin/tar xpf /tmp/smt.tbz2 -C /tmp: No such file or directory
```

It looks like the `su` command does not interpret correctly the command after `-c`.

Comment: Also see [Run sudo command in Qt QProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32063190/608639), [Executing Linux command as root in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7036588/608639), [How to get root permission inside Qt program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19840163/608639), [QProcess, communicate with 'su' command](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24898-QProcess-communicate-with-su-command), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are quoting the command to run explicitly: `QProcess` goes to some lengths to ensure parameters are passed as-is rather than being split any further.

Instead try...

```
QProcess::execute("/bin/su", {"-", "user", "-c", "/bin/tar xpf /tmp/smt.tbz2 -C /tmp"});
```